# How to reset a TextBox that has TextMode="Date" to default?

Tags: asp.net

I want the default state of this control when clciking reset button.

```html
<asp:TextBox TextMode="Date" runat="server" ID="txtMosqueEstab"></asp:TextBox>
```

I have tried :
txtMosqueEstab.Text = String.Empty;

Answer (score 0):

Reset it by having:

txtMosqueEstab.Text = "";